Why is there no attention aggregate?
I read this:
'Nama-rupa' is simply the aggregates:

And what, bhikkhus, is name-and-form? Feeling, perception, volition,
contact, attention: this is called name. The four great elements and
the form derived from the four great elements: this is called form.
Thus this name and this form are together called name-and-form.
SN 12.2

Why is attention not one the aggregates?

Since the  primary point the Buddha is making about the aggregates is that they're problematic when we cling to them, can you describe in what ways, and/or in what situations, you find yourself problematically clinging to attention, in ways that lead to dukkha/suffering? Understanding what's behind your question would help in answering it.

Why is attention not one the aggregates? What? I don't get it. attention is in your quote. As an aggregate of the Nama(aka mind, conciseness). Can someone please explain?

related: https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/21049/19249

Attention is a product of/maintained by volition/intention (which is sankhara aggregate).

thank you BE :)

it's something else, not just intention, not even right intention, but like a background error, preperations?

Yes, Preparations are also sankhara aggregate

Good question.
So by that logic you should also ask why there is no phassa aggregate.
My logic :
The reason attention is not aggregate is because it  is tools to bring Nama and rupa closer. No attention no NamaRupa. E.g If you are in a bus there is lot of sound but your attention is on the talk between two people.  So other sound Is not able to generate full Nama-rupa.
Attention is like a catalyst. with it presence Nama and Rupa gets paired. and this contact of Nama and rupa is called Phassa. then salayatana and then a qualifiable object its touched(phassa) and now it is 5 Aggregate. 5 Aggregate is a complete experience. Nama-Rupa is Raw.
With this logic Nama-Rupa is only present moment. however 5 Aggregates are past,present,future too.

The vedana in namarupa mostly neutral. But not alwase. In case of primodial object which induces fear, lust, anger, covetiousness. There is subconscious feeling(and bodily sensation too) even before you recognise the object(salaytana paccaya phassa).

In fact vedana as cittasankhara is present even before namarupa. As in avijja(aasava) paccaya sankhara.

My understanding is that it's because attention is present kamma, the type of kamma where you have a high degree of freedom to choose and which can be either skillful or unskilful. The aggregates are old kamma, an area where we have a more limited degree of freedom. The sense bases are definitely described as old kamma - SN 35.145 - and it makes sense to me to apply the same to the aggregates.
Take the famous simile about getting shot with an arrow - you're already shot, you can't do anything about that fact, but you can choose to take the arrow out and dress the wound. Or you can choose to stab yourself with another arrow. The first arrow is the aggregates: old kamma, which you haven't got much choice over - there are some pains that will arise which you can't do much with but endure. Treating the wound is appropriate attention: contemplating in such a way that you don't suffer mentally on account of the aggregates. Stabbing yourself is inappropriate attention: contemplating in such a way that you lay claim to the body and the pain, making yourself and everyone around you miserable.
Since the Buddha frequently declared attention to be the most important internal factor in deciding our happiness or suffering (see the Anguttara Ones), he probably wanted to make sure that it wouldn't be viewed in a context that would encourage people to think that they have little choice over what to do with it. He wanted us to realise that this is the most crucial area in life where we have the power and freedom to make the wise choices that can lead us to total freedom from suffering and stress.

+1 for pointing out that appropriate attention is utmost important. But there seems to be always an element of intention to our attention as mentioned in this answer.

Read Name and Form and Rupa.
The form is built by Rupa.The form is some collection of Rupa.


Why is attention not one the aggregates?

It is.
From your quote,

And what, bhikkhus, is name-and-form? Feeling, perception, volition, contact, attention: this is called name.

Feeling, perception, volition, contact, attention , attention is in there.
Attention is an aggregate of the Name.(aka conciseness).
